# Laravel exception: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting this error just by instantiating a Model and setting a property.

```
$order_datail = new OrderDetail;
$order_detail->quantity = $product['quantity'];
```

I'm searching for hours for the cause of this problem but can't find it.

The constructor of OrderDetail is executed. table is order_details, but even by setting protected $table = 'order_details', I'm still getting this error. And yes there is a column 'quantity' in this table.

Strange thing is that I've no problem with other models.

```
$order = new Order;
$order->pickup_date = $request['date'];
$order->pickup_time = $request['pickupTime'];
```

The above code runs fine.

Model OrderDetail:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class OrderDetail extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

public function replaceds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Replaced');
}
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order');
}
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}
public function collis()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Colli');
}
}
```

Anyone that knows what can be the cause of this?

Comment: can you show your model?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question

Comment: Please correct your speling in $order_datail = new OrderDetail; it should be "order_detail"

Comment: You can't be serious... Checked it so many times. Facepalm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spelling error on `$order_datail = new OrderDetail;`
Change it to: `$order_detail = new OrderDetail;`

Comment: You can't be serious... Checked it so many times. Facepalm!